# How to use "argparse" argument across python files?

Tags: python, argparse

Let's say I have a main.py and a subfile.py.

1. main.py

```
import subfile #Writen by myself. I want to share argparse with it

import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='test',formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument('--a', type=int, default=0, help='test')
args = parser.parse_args()

args.a=0
subfile.fun()

args.a=1
subfile.fun()

args.a=0
subfile.fun()
```

2.subfile.py

```
xxxxxsome operation here to use args in main.pyxxxx
# In tensorflow wrapped argparse, I just need to define the same ArgumentParser to use args defined in main.py. 
# But it's not suitable for "argparse", which would cause conflicts.

def fun():
    if args.a==0:
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```

In main.py I use argparse to pass arguments, and main.py use subfile.py.

Now, I want to use args define in main.py, how can I do?

(The codes are an simplified example described the problem, which can't be solved by reorganized code and has to be solved by using args in subfile.py. )

Thanks for your help! I have been torture by some bugs for the whole day and your answer would help me out. Appreciated!

---

edit:
Actually I know how to pass a paramter to a funciton. But as I said above, I writed the example code just for the key solution: is how to use **the library "argparse"** across python file, which is supported in a similar library in tensorflow "FLAG".

Comment: just pass `a` as argument to `fun` --> `def fun(a)`

Comment: @陈绍伍, check if my answer works. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can add another file, let's call it `arguments.py` for example.

Then include at the top of both `main.py` and `subfile.py` the following line:

```
from arguments import args
```

You then move all the code relating to parsing the command line arguments to `arguments.py`.

This way both the modules in `main.py` and `subfile.py` have access to the same `args` object.

Answer (score 0):

## def

---

When you define a function, if you need parameters, you can add them between the parentesis.
This is the model:

```
def fun(par: type) -> ReturnedType:
    pass
```

For example:

```
def fun(a: int) -> None:
    if a == 0:
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")
```

Then, when calling `subfile.fun()` add the argument like this:

```
subfile.fun(a = a)
```

or like this:

```
subfile.fun(a)
```

## return

---

Remember your function doesn't return anything.
If you want to assign to a variable "yes" or "no" you can do like this:

```
def fun(a: int) -> str:
    if a == 0:
        return "Yes"
    else:
        return "No"
```

If you want to return only "yes" or "no", you might like to return a boolean instead:

```
def fun(a: int) -> bool:
    if a == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

You can also write the if statement in one line:

```
print('Yes') if (a == 0) else print('No)
```

## import

---

To import `subfile.py` the file should be in the same directory.
Otherwise you have to do like this:

```
from sys import path
# Imagine you need C:\\Python\MyFolder\subfile.py
path.append(r"C:\\Python\MyFolder")
import subfile
```

Comment: I know how to pass a paramter to a funciton. But as I said above, I writed the example code just for the key solution: how to use the library "argparse" across python file, which is supported in a similar library in tensorflow "FLAG". Could you help me with this "argparse" library?

Comment: <s>@陈绍伍, why don't you simply put the definition of fun() in the same file?</s> Now I understand, but I don't know your answer, sorry.

Comment: Please don't ask others to accept your answer or to upvote it.

Comment: @WaiHaLee, ok, I did it just because who asked the question was new to the site, so probably them didn't know about this

Comment: The user who asked this question has been a member for two years. If you must talk about upvotes or accepting an answer, don't put it in your answer.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I won't do it anymore